# wikipedia API JSON isn't recognized by $.getJSON() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wikipedia-api

I know already that this method works for other JSON formatted data but not the wikipedia API JSON output as listed here.  Any help would be great:

```
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=starwars', function(data) {
    $("p").html(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: do you get any errors in your browsers developer tools console? (I'm guessing some error regarding CORS will hsow up)

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda and good call.  This is the error in my Chrome Dev Tools:  'XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=starwars. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `callback`

```js
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=starwars&callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to `$.ajax` with a *jsonp* dataType:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=starwars",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      $("pre").html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: How relative are you to @CodeiSir? You both have the same biography.

Comment: @AdamAzad I'm not, it's an auto-generated biography by SO ^^

Comment: You might want to work on your about section then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Jaromanda X is right, you'll need to use a `callback` function to sort this out. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests/en

Comment: Thanks Eduardo for the wikipedia page.  The callback function indeed sorted it out.