# How to use Wikipedia's API to search for multiple articles using JS and/or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wikipedia-api

I'm using FreeCodeCamp but cannot for the life of me figure out how to use Wikipedia's API. Here's what I've had so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: apiURL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#api").html(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
});
```

The apiURL is obviously the url I need to use, but so far nothing out of the 100s of things I've tried have gotten this to work.

Please, I understand I'm probably far off but I really have a very bad understanding of how to work with APIs.

Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search_and_discovery) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34574642/2151050)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by many different ways one of them is like this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=starwars",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#api").html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));      
    }
  });
});
```

In above piece of code, a blank space is being used after api.php, this space is not required. I think this has been added by mistakenly.

Comment: You're my hero! A few questions just so I understand completely: 1) do you always put a space between the base api url and the parameters? 2) what is the significance of null, 3 in the stringify function 3)How can i use the api to also include miniature descriptions of each page? Thanks again!

Comment: @Payton No, the space was an error. The second parameter specifies a replacer function, which we don't want to use. We do however want to use the third parameter which enables pretty-printing of the JSON output (3 is the number of spaces to use). In order to specify the third parameter, we need to specify an empty second parameter as well.